# What is DSMLawmo? How to remove it?

Tags: samsung, tablet, malware, antivirus

A recent AVG anti-virus scan on my Android tablet flagged DSMLawmo as malware. The antivirus states that it can't be removed and that DSMLawmo was pre-installed.

The tablet is a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 inch and it runs Android 4.2.2 Jelly Bean. Any information on DSMLawmo would be appreciated.

Comment: The antivirus scan that informed you that DSMLawmo was maybe a [false positive.](https://community.webroot.com/t5/Webroot-SecureAnywhere-Complete/Removing-DSMLawmo-from-my-Galaxy-S3/m-p/180882#M10477)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DSMLawmo is a Samsung system app that is preinstalled, it is not malware but it does have many of the characteristics of malware likely leading to a false positive detection, the description is:

> "DSM states for "Dedicated Security Management " Which allows this app
>   to get a full control over the phone using voice channel only...
>   Dsmlawmo is to get full control over the phone, track it, reset and
>   stuff like that. It's probably to control and repair the phone
>   remotely when calling cs"

[Source - XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=30946481&postcount=4)

A simple Google search will get several results showing that this has been preinstalled on most Samsung devices since at least 2012. It can be safely Frozen or Disabled, if those are options.

This could also lead into the fact that unless you installing software from Unknown Sources (you had to turn on the ability manually), you likely do not need any antivirus or security app on your device and it will cause more of a hindrance than do any good.

Comment: What is the source of the quoted text?

Comment: Google search "DSMLawmo" and it is the first result... http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s2/help/dsmlawmo-t1863011 post #4